# Detect screenshot from background task UWP

Tags: c#, background, screenshot, uwp

I want to know when a user takes a screenshot on his device, using the lock/unlock + volume up buttons for phones or printscreen key for PC. The app should probably run in background but I have never heard of those kind of event in UWP. Does it exist?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible with official API.

Comment: okay, thanks for this quick answer btw :)